# bitcoind - how to find out what is affecting the verificationprogress

Tags: bitcoind, verification

### Problem

Bitcoind verificationprogress continues to go up and down around .99999xxx and never finish verifying

### Background

Looking for any insight here, had a node that went down and upon bringing it back up it spent about 18 hours between .999992 and .9999998 and just keeps bouncing up and down there.

I'm assuming there is some verification or validation and as blocks are coming in the number goes down slightly but I can't find any stats to help me figure out what is remaining or if there are any issues.

Comment: I've tried stopping and restarting a few times and left it going for like I mentioned over 18 hours and never saw any real change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verification progress is an estimate, based on how many transactions have been seen versus known statistics about the transaction rate on the network.

If the latest block timestamp is in the past, the verification progress will be below 1. If the latest block timestamp is in the future, the verification progress will be above 1.

Nothing is wrong by it persistently below 1. It's a side effect of blocks only appearing every 10 minutes.

Comment: Woops I was having some problems before this and thought I had seen it at 1 before and assumed my node was having problems, thanks for this!